# Unable to instantiate instrumentation ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, junit, manifest

I am trying to set up JUnit tests for Android and I have the manifest and such set up but I keep getting this errror:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate instrumentation ComponentInfo {com.example.Android/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.Android-1.apk:/data/app/com.example.Android-1.apk]
```

Test Class:

```
  public class ConnectionToSiteTest extends AndroidTestCase{
    private final String emailUsername = "testUser@gmail.com";
    private final String password = "test";
    private final String features = "222222";
    private String commands;

    public void testCommandReturn(){
        requestToSite();

        assertEquals("222222", commands);
    }

    private void requestToSite(){
        try {
            // Create params for connection including 3sec timeout
            // on connection and 5sec timeout on socket
            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeoutConnection = 3000;
            int timeoutSocket = 5000;

            // Set the timeouts
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
                    timeoutConnection);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeoutSocket);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

            // Create the data entities
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://example.com/AndroidCommands");
            HttpResponse response;

            // Set POST data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emailUsername",
                    emailUsername));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",
                    password));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("features",
                    features));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Query the server and store the user's ID
            response = httpClient.execute(post);

            // Grabs the command string from response headers and processes them
            commands = (String) response.getHeaders("commands")[0].getValue();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
   android:targetPackage="edu.neumont.MillerK.Android" android:label="Tests for My App" />
<activity
        android:name="com.example.Android.ConnectionToSiteTest">            
    </activity>
```

Test Suite Class:

```
    public class AllTests extends TestSuite {
    public static Test suite() {
        return new TestSuiteBuilder(AllTests.class).includeAllPackagesUnderHere().build();
    }
}
```

I've been trying to find the same exception somewhere that it has been fixed, but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the tests are in a proper Android Test project? You can add one in Eclipse by right-clicking your project -> Android Tools -> Add Android Test Project. All your tests should be put in that project.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that Eclipse is not correctly building the package. When it happened to me, exactly same error, I looked it up and easily found the solution.
In my case I was missing **Android Package Builder** under *YourProject->Properties->Builders*.
To add it again, I just added a few lines (the ApkBuilder ones) to Eclipse's .project file. You can have a different problem, but check that your .project looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>xxx-it</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
        <project>xxx-project</project>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Comment: Oh I assumed that the package names in the AndroidManifest.xml are correct. Both under the manifest and instrumentation tags.